# How to Delete ALL .txt files From a Directory using PHP

Tags: php, unlink

Im trying to Delete ALL Text files from a directory using a php script.

Here is what I have tried.....

```
<?php array_map('unlink', glob("/paste/*.txt")); ?>
```

I dont get an Error when I run this, yet It doesnt do the job.

Is there a snippet for this? Im not sure what else to try.

Comment: There isnt an error, I said that above.

Comment: Is the path `/paste/*.txt` right ? The paste dir is under `/`

Comment: Baba Helped me, I wasnt using the Full Path, I had to inlude /home/user/ ect... I Got it now, have to wait to accept his answer.

Comment: You should know you are using the full path, the problem is you are using the wrong full path. Any path start with `/` is a full path.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your Implementation works all you need to do is use `Use full PATH`

Example

```
$fullPath = __DIR__ . "/test/" ;
array_map('unlink', glob( "$fullPath*.log"))
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I Didn't know what the prob was, Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 3):

I expanded the submitted answers a little bit so that you can flexibly and recursively unlink text files located underneath as it's often the case.

```
// @param  string  Target directory
// @param  string  Target file extension
// @return boolean True on success, False on failure

function unlink_recursive($dir_name, $ext) {

    // Exit if there's no such directory
    if (!file_exists($dir_name)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Open the target directory
    $dir_handle = dir($dir_name);

    // Take entries in the directory one at a time
    while (false !== ($entry = $dir_handle->read())) {

        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $abs_name = "$dir_name/$entry";

        if (is_file($abs_name) && preg_match("/^.+\.$ext$/", $entry)) {
            if (unlink($abs_name)) {
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Recurse on the children if the current entry happens to be a "directory"
        if (is_dir($abs_name) || is_link($abs_name)) {
            unlink_recursive($abs_name, $ext);
        }

    }

    $dir_handle->close();
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the method below but be careful. Make sure you have permissions to delete files. If all else fails, send an exec command and let linux do it

```
static function getFiles($directory) {
    $looper = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($looper) as $filename => $cur) {
        $ext = trim($cur->getExtension());
        if($ext=="txt"){
           // remove file: 
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have modified submitted answers and made my own version,

in which i have made function which will iterate recursively in current directory and its all child level directories,

and it will unlink all the files with extension of `.txt` or whatever `.[extension]` you want to remove from **all the directories, sub-directories and its all child level directories**.

i have used :
[`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) From the php doc:

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern
>   according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is
>   similar to the rules used by common shells.

i have used **`GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag because it will iterate through only directories**, so it will be easier to get only directories and unlink the desired files from that directory.

```
<?php

//extension of files you want to remove.
$remove_ext = 'txt';
//remove desired extension files in current directory
array_map('unlink', glob("./*.$remove_ext"));

// below function will remove desired extensions files from all the directories recursively.
function removeRecursive($directory, $ext) {

    array_map('unlink', glob("$directory/*.$ext"));

    foreach (glob("$directory/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
            removeRecursive($dir, $ext);
    }
    return true;
}

//traverse through all the directories in current directory 
foreach (glob('./*',GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    removeRecursive($dir, $remove_ext);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wonder how to delete (for example: All PDF files under public directory) you can do this:

```
array_map('unlink', glob( public_path('*.pdf')));
```